How to Make D3 SVG responsive in react with viewbox
How can I make my D3.js line chart responsive and scrollable horizontally?
Currently, when I resize the window, the SVG size does not adjust, and the chart is not responsive. The chart width dynamically increases based on the data feed, similar to an ECG chart.
Here's what I need:

The SVG size should adjust when the window size changes.
The chart should be horizontally scrollable when the SVG width exceeds the container size.

I have tried using the viewBox attribute, but it is not making the SVG responsive. The width of the SVG is calculated based on the JSON data length multiplied by the width of each box (e.g., 4 * 290).

const svgRef = useRef(null);
const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
svg.attr('width', width)
.attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} 600`)
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet');

return <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>;


Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553402/d3-change-svg-dimensions-on-resize-window
